# Is there any use in obliviating the town with rainfall after photographs have been taken?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* MACUSA fears that their secret has been exposed to the world so they obliviated the town with rainfall:

[image]

Before obliviating the town photographers had already taken some pictures using their cameras:

[image]

So is there any use in obliviating the town with rainfall after photographs have been taken?

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn: I think it's rather clear, awkward phrasing nonwithstanding: Is there any use in casting `obliviate` on the whole town, when the photographers have already taken pictures (and thus will have photographic evidence)? (Cannot answer as I haven't seen the movie yet, but that seems to be the question here.)

Answer (score 10):

### Yes

During that scene, we see everything that is affected by the obliviating rain. This includes newspapers. Rather than getting soaked and unreadable, the newspapers are instead magically changed to read something else. In addition, people inside (who aren't in immediate contact with the rain) are also affected by its magical effects. So this means that it's safe to assume that the rain would cause any photos, or even cameras that have taken photos, to be affected and thus have the "evidence" removed.

edit: Thank you to @Mennyg for pointing out, in Deathly Hallows Pt 1 Hermione obliviates her parents and as a result all photographs are magically altered as well.

Comment: I remember something similar happening in Deathly Hallows Part 1 when Hermione modifies her parents memories, all the photos with her in it were modified too. Not a real proof though as "The films are rubbish"